# Почему не работает замыкание во втором примере кода?

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

В книге Выразительный JavaScript 3-е издание (2018) встретил два примера кода на замыкания:

```js
function wrapValue (n){ 

  let local = n;
  return () => local;

}

let wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
console.log(wrap1());
// 1
let wrap2 = wrapValue(2);
console.log(wrap2());
// 2
```

Первый пример работает и даже понятен мне, вот второй:

```js
function multiplier(factor) {
  return number => number * factor;
}
let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(S));
// 10
```

Как должен работать второй пример? (понятно, что вывести 10 в консоль, я имею ввиду алгоритм) У меня в консоль выводится ошибка

> 5 is not definded

Проверяю в хроме. Даже если 5 будет определена, по моему функция должна работать так:

В первый раз в строке

```
let twice = multiplier(2);
```

стрелочная функция умножает `number` (который вроде как должен быть `undefinded`) на `2` В результате , и мы получим `NaN`. Во второй раз получается `NaN * 5`, в итоге `NaN`. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает второй пример кода и почему он должен вывести 10 в консоль?

Comment: `console.log(twice(S));` - это не 5 а S какая-то, что ли, которая интерпретируется как переменная, её нет - ошибка, ничего не работает.. Удалите и вставьте сами туда цифру 5 - всё должно заработать

Comment: @InDevX Все работает. Но мне все равно не понятно, почему вывелось 10, а не NaN

Comment: У Вас twice содержит функцию `number => number * factor (2)`, то есть - `let twice = function (number) { return number * 2 }`.. То есть, аргумент (5) умножается на 2, 5*2=10